# Does SQLiteDatabase.query uses PreparedStatements ?

Tags: android, sqlite, prepared-statement

When I query my database with user inputs in Android, I normally use [SQliteDatabase.query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), with proper use of SelectionArgs.

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(UserEntity.TABLE,
            new String[]{UserEntity.COLUMN_ID, UserEntity.COLUMN_USERNAME, UserEntity.COLUMN_FIRSTNAME,UserEntity.COLUMN_LASTNAME,...},
            UserEntity.COLUMN_USERNAME + "=?",
            new String[]{username},
            null, null, null);
```

Is it enough to prevent SQL injections ? Or should I use PreparedStatements before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommendation to use prepared statements comes from PHP, where some old API did not allow SQL parameters (`?`) except when using a prepared statement.

But parameters and prepared statements are orthogonal concepts. To prevent injections (and avoid string/blob formatting problems), you need only parameters. (And `query()` gives you that.)

A prepared statement is useful only when you want to execute it multiple times.

(As it happens, `query()` indeed uses a prepared statement internally, but this is a consequence of the SQLite API, and is of no concern to you.)